# spyOn(Date, 'now') does not work in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, firefox, jasmine

In Jasmine I want to `spyOn` and mock the return value of `Date.now`.

```
spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(500);
```

The above works in Chrome, but not in Firefox 20.0 or IE 11 (in IE 10 mode).

Can anyone confirm that this is expected behavior?

I am using:

```
"jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
"karma-jasmine": "0.3.5",
```

Comment: Can you alter the value of `Date.now` in the problematic browsers? (i.e., if you do `Date.now = "foo"`, and then call it, do you correctly see not-a-function errors, or are they absent, indicating a failure to overwrite the `now` property?

Comment: The former. I thought maybe FF20 froze the obejct or similar, but I can overwrite `Date.now` in FF20.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check on IE but on Firefox 44.0.2 it's working.
Check this http://jsfiddle.net/L6zy6h6k/

```
var foo = function () {
   return Date.now();
}

describe("foo", function() {

  it("calls Date.now", function() {
    spyOn(Date, 'now').and.returnValue(500);
    var result = foo();
    expect(Date.now).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(result).toEqual(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: OK, may be browser version related. I have FF 20.